# Weird lighting effect using a point light on a skydome

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, shader, lighting

I have a problem with my lighting. When the light goes over a vertex point or line the lighting gets this weird look. (It's supposed to be round.) I've been trying all kind of things but I can't find out why this is happening.

[image: Weird looking normals]

I create a skydome and normalize its possition

```
double deltaLatitude = XM_PI / segments;
double deltaLongitude = XM_PI * 2.0 / segments;
int index = 0;
D3DXCOLOR bottomColor = D3DXCOLOR(0.529f, 0.807f, 0.821f, 1.0f);
D3DXCOLOR topColor = D3DXCOLOR(0.179f, 0.557f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

for (int i = 1; i < segments; i++)
{
    double r0 = sin(i * deltaLatitude);
    double y0 = cos(i * deltaLatitude);

    for (int j = 0; j < segments; j++)
    {
        double x0 = r0 * sin(j * deltaLongitude);
        double z0 = r0 * cos(j * deltaLongitude);

        D3DXVECTOR3 v = D3DXVECTOR3(x0, y0, z0);//create normal based on possition (-1 <> 1)
        D3DXVec3Normalize(&v, &v);//normalize
        vertPos.push_back(Vertex(x0, y0, z0, lerp(bottomColor, topColor, y0), v));
    }
}

vertPos.push_back(Vertex(0, 1, 0, lerp(bottomColor, topColor, 1), D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)));
vertPos.push_back(Vertex(0, -1, 0, lerp(bottomColor, topColor, -1), D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));

for (int i = 0; i < segments - 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < segments; j++)
    {
        indices.push_back(segments * i + j);
        indices.push_back(segments * i + (j + 1) % segments);
        indices.push_back(segments * (i + 1) + (j + 1) % segments);
        indices.push_back(segments * i + j);
        indices.push_back(segments * (i + 1) + (j + 1) % segments);
        indices.push_back(segments * (i + 1) + j);
    }
}

// create the faces of the top of the dome
for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
{
    indices.push_back(segments * (segments - 1));
    indices.push_back((i + 1) % segments);
    indices.push_back(i);
}

// create the faces of the bottom of the dome
for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
{
    indices.push_back(segments * (segments - 1) + 1);
    indices.push_back(segments * (segments - 2) + i);
    indices.push_back(segments * (segments - 2) + (i + 1) % segments);
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 inPos : POSITION, float2 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD, float4 inColor : COLOR, float3 normal : NORMAL)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    output.Pos = mul(inPos, WVP);

    output.worldPos = mul(inPos, World);
    output.normal = mul(normal, World);

    output.Color = inColor;

    return output;
}
```

And here is the pixel shader:

```
float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 diffuse = input.Color;
    float skyColor = light.spos.a;
    float4 sunColor = float4(500.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 1.0f);

    float3 finalColor = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float3 finalAmbient = diffuse * skyColor;

    float sunRange = 1000.0f;

    float3 lightToPixelVec = light.spos - input.worldPos;

    float d = length(lightToPixelVec);

    if( d > sunRange ){
        return float4(finalAmbient, diffuse.a);
    }

    //Turn lightToPixelVec into a unit length vector describing
    //the pixels direction from the lights position
    lightToPixelVec /= d;

    //Calculate how much light the pixel gets by the angle
    //in which the light strikes the pixels surface
    float howMuchLight = dot(lightToPixelVec, input.normal);

    //If light is striking the front side of the pixel
    if( howMuchLight > 0.0f )
    {   
        //Add light to the finalColor of the pixel
        finalColor += howMuchLight * finalAmbient * sunColor;

        //Calculate Light's Falloff factor
        finalColor /= 10.0f + (0.01 * d) + (0.01 * (d*d));
    }   
    finalColor = saturate(finalColor + finalAmbient);

    return float4(finalColor, diffuse.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to think about faces to get the normals at the vertices. It's just a hemisphere, right, so the normal is just the vector from the centre of the sphere (the origin I guess) to the vertex, but then you should normalise it to a length of 1. So the normal of a vertex is simply its coordinates normalised.

Comment: Thanks that made it a bit faster, but it still creates the same effect for the lighting. Any ideas what can cause that?

Comment: Something is not interpolating properly, and that's often down to something in the vertex shader, so can I see that? Also, I don't understand that falloff factor thing so I'd like to see the results with that taken out, and similarly for that d > sunRange thing.

Comment: The falloff factor is just how much light this point light gives off at a certain d (distance) this means the further away the pixel is from the sun possition, the less light is added.

d > sunRange is just to check if the pixel is whiting the range of 1000.0f when I remove this, my sky would be black.

I've added the vertex shader for you.

Comment: You got a texCoord in the vertex shader parameters but I don't see it in the vertices you pushed.

Comment: Yes, I don't use it. It's added by the constructor: `Vertex(float x, float y, float z, D3DXCOLOR color, D3DXVECTOR3 normal) : pos(x,y,z), color(color), texCoord(0.0f, 0.0f), normal(normal) {}`

Comment: Well then I'm back to what I said before. I don't know what the picture should look like with that falloff and cutoff in there. I don't even know how big d is. If you show me the results with that stuff taken out perhaps I can narrow it down a bit.

Comment: To be honest, thanks to you I think I already know what is causing the problem. The sun is located between 2 faces, I think that (because of the amount of segments), it is further away from the corner and so not adding as much light there. I'll do some research and come back later.

Comment: I've added 0.2 to the suns x pos and now it looks just fine, I know this is just avoiding the actual problem... but hey, it works for now..

Thanks for that, I was looking for a solution for 2 days...

Comment: Sounds like your sun is incredibly close - AFAICT your radius is 1. Then the picture would make sense. How does it look if the sun is at (5,10,5)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, that was indeed the problem..

I was using the exact same coords for the sun as for the sphere (with a few more points in between: `double deltaLatitude = XM_PI / 180;
double deltaLongitude = XM_PI * 2.0 / 180;`) All I did to fix it was edit the scale of the suns possition compared to the scale of the sky dome

Answer (score 0):

Traditional OpenGL fixed function pipeline illumination does the calculations only at the vertices and interpolates in between. Depending on the topology of the mesh you might have a rasterization topology discontinuity there caused by the way OpenGL interpolates between vertices.

Solution: Use per fragment illumination, implemented in a fragment shader.

BTW: Why do you want to apply illumination to a skydome in the first place?